# VCSA Authentication via rest API not working

Tags: vsphere, esx

Any idea why my Authentication not working via rest api call to VCSA ?
I am using VCSA 7.0.3
I created new local user with read only access. I tested web login, is working.
But when I tested API login via postman or curl, python, I get always this error message :  UNAUTHENTICATED, Authentication required."
Even though, I used the same user login credentials.
I tested also with my admin user, same error.

Any idea what is wrong ?

API url should be  correct per VCSA api-explorer

https:///api/vcenter/authentication/token

[image]